# How do I merge these two queries together?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT MIN( a.severity ), CONCAT_WS(",", a.dev_id, a.object_id ) AS tuple 
FROM net.alerts AS a INNER JOIN net.deviceinfo AS c ON c.id = a.dev_id AND 
c.peer = ( SELECT value FROM local.settings WHERE setting="server_id" ) WHERE 1 
AND (a.dev_id, a.object_id) IN ( (13,4164),(45,-1),(145,995),(188,-1) ) GROUP BY tuple


SELECT MIN( a.severity ), CONCAT_WS(",", b.device_id, b.object_id ) AS tuple 
FROM net.alerts AS a INNER JOIN local.conditions AS b ON a.condition_id = b.condition_id WHERE 1 
AND(b.device_id, b.object_id) IN ((13,4164),(45,-1),(145,995),(188,-1) ) Group BY tuple
```

I have these tables, and in the alerts and conditions tables, they all have the device_id and object_id, but they maybe different, so I'm trying to retrieve all data of that composite.

Comment: Are you expecting to only get one row back from each of those queries, or did you forget to include your `GROUP BY`s?

Comment: Oh, I forgot the group by..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you try to do but I guess you need to use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html).

By the way why do you write `WHERE 1 AND condition` and not `WHERE condition` ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it'd be best to work on a single query, but maybe UNION would work for you as you say you just want to merge the result:

```
(SELECT MIN( a.severity ), CONCAT_WS(",", a.dev_id, a.object_id ) AS tuple 
FROM net.alerts AS a INNER JOIN net.deviceinfo AS c ON c.id = a.dev_id AND 
c.peer = ( SELECT value FROM local.settings WHERE setting="server_id" ) WHERE 1 AND 
(a.dev_id, a.object_id) IN ( (13,4164),(45,-1),(145,995),(188,-1) ))

UNION 

(SELECT MIN( a.severity ), CONCAT_WS(",", b.device_id, b.object_id ) AS tuple 
FROM net.alerts AS a INNER JOIN local.conditions AS b ON 
a.condition_id = b.condition_id WHERE 1 AND(b.device_id, b.object_id) IN ((13,4164),
(45,-1),(145,995),(188,-1) ))
```

- Use "UNION ALL" to allow duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to use [union](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union.php) or [union all](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php), depending on what kind of join you want.
So for twi qyery results `n1` and `n2`:

- Union -  `x < n1+n2`  - will remove duplicates
- Union All - `x == n1+n2` -will save duplicates

So your code should look like this:

```
(SELECT MIN( a.severity ), CONCAT_WS(",", a.dev_id, a.object_id ) AS tuple 
FROM net.alerts AS a INNER JOIN net.deviceinfo AS c ON c.id = a.dev_id AND 
c.peer = ( SELECT value FROM local.settings WHERE setting="server_id" ) WHERE 1 
AND (a.dev_id, a.object_id) IN ( (13,4164),(45,-1),(145,995),(188,-1) ) GROUP BY tuple)

 UNION

(SELECT MIN( a.severity ), CONCAT_WS(",", b.device_id, b.object_id ) AS tuple 
FROM net.alerts AS a INNER JOIN local.conditions AS b ON a.condition_id = b.condition_id WHERE 1 
AND(b.device_id, b.object_id) IN ((13,4164),(45,-1),(145,995),(188,-1) ) Group BY tuple)
```

You ned to remember: number and names of your query columns must match exactly.